# Having trouble with custom login flow in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

First I'll explain what I'm trying to accomplish:

- users navigate to "/login" in my application
- a **nonce** is generated, and used to created a URL to redirect users to an external service
- users authenticate with the external service, and are redirected back to my application with a GET parameter
- the GET parameter is validated using the **nonce**, and user info is retrieved from the external service
- the user is loaded from my application's database (or created if they don't exist) and logged in
- after logging in, user roles dictate what this user has access to

I had originally implemented this via controller actions where a loginAction does the redirecting to the external service, and the external service redirects back to an authAction. In the authAction, the user is loaded (or created) and programatically logged in.

I thought the previous approach might be hack-ish, and attempted to try the [SimplePreAuth tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html), but I'm having no luck.

What would be my best approach?

Comment: Ok, but what are you receiving? Errors? What is the problem?

Comment: First I want to know what approach I should be taking.

Comment: Nobody will help you. Where is the source code? Where are you stuck? SimplePreAuth is possible solution. If you think that is not powerful enough then see this cookbook tutorial [http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html). You will have to inspire yourself in source of existing providers. Or you can try to find existing bundle - maybe.

Comment: All I was asking was what the best approach would be for my needs. (ie. A link to a tutorial.) I'm not asking someone to write out a solution for me. Anyways, I came up with a solution that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I basically just went with the solution I thought might have been hack-ish.